# Platform-dependent VS Code workspace recommended extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**Core Question**: Is there a setting that conditionally recommends extensions based on the user's platform? (e.g. recommend `remote-wsl`, but ONLY on Windows)

I was reading about the VS Code *[Workspace Recommended Extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_workspace-recommended-extensions)*, which solved my problem of "wanting to recommend a base set of extensions for a project", by adding this to the workspace `.vscode/extensions.json`:

```json
{
    "recommendations": [
        "ms-python.python",
        "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
    ]
}
```

... but for Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) users, I *also want* to recommend:

```json
"ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl"
```

**Other Notes**: I frequently work with students who have a mix of macOS, Windows, and WSL machines. My goal is to simplify environment setup, since students are often new to programming. The WSL extension so far has been crucial to create a consistent development experience.

Comment: Platform specific json settings in the same json file (for easy maintainability) is not supported quite well yet by VSCode team. See open ticket here for this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5595

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of there being such a mechanism- at least not for extensions.json. There is such a thing as a ["platform-specific extension"](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#platformspecific-extensions), but I don't think that has relevance to this question. You could try using [profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles) instead and just make and export a profile for each platform- a bit of a maintenance burden, but the best I can currently think to suggest trying.

If you really want extensions.json to support some mechanism for this, then I'd suggest to [raise a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Comment: there is already an open ticket for something like this at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5595

Comment: @Tryer I'm aware of that ticket. I don't see how it's related to this question so I didn't mention it. settings.json and extensions.json are different things.